# Logic of the function 'number()' used in USBHOSTHidKdb firmware code

Tags: c, ftdi

```
I was looking for Keyboard firmware codes on FTDI website. I came across few codes such as USBHostHIDKdb, USBHostHID and USBHostHid2. In all the firmware codes I have noticed number function. But I am not getting the logic of it. Below I have written its code. Please check it and help me understand its logic.

/*
** number
**
** Print a character in the terminal application.
**
** Parameters:  val - Byte to be printed
** Returns: void
** Comments:
*/
void number(unsigned char val)
{
    unsigned char nibble;

    nibble = (val >> 4) + '0';
    if (nibble > '9') nibble += ('A' - '9' - 1);

    vos_dev_write(hUART, &nibble, (uint16) 1, NULL);

    nibble = (val & 15) + '0';
    if (nibble > '9') nibble += ('A' - '9' - 1);

    vos_dev_write(hUART, &nibble, (uint16) 1, NULL);
}
```

Function where number() is used in USBHostHIDkdb.c. The code attaches driver to the host. And writes the keyboard usage ids to the UART when the key stroke event happens.

```
void firmware()
{

    do
    {
        open_drivers();

        if (status == PORT_STATE_ENUMERATED)
        {
            message("Enumeration complete\r\n");

            attach_drivers();

            // get report descriptor code, set idle code, get idle code
```

if (status == USBHOSTHID_OK)
            {
                    while (1)
                    {
                        if (vos_dev_read(hUSBHOST_HID, buf, 8, &num_read) == USBHOSTHID_OK)
                        {

```
                        for (byteCount = 0; byteCount < num_read; byteCount++)
                        {
                            number(buf[byteCount]);
                        }
                        message(eol);
                    }

                }
                }

} while (1);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`number()` takes a byte, and writes its value in hex (as two characters).

Let's examine some parts of the code.

The following extract the high [nibble](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble) of `val`:

```
(val >> 4)
```

The following extract the low [nibble](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble) of `val`:

```
(val & 15)
```

The following coverts a value between 0 and 15 to the hex digit (`0`..`9`, `A`..`F`):

```
nibble = (...) + '0';
if (nibble > '9') nibble += ('A' - '9' - 1);
```